# Irreducibility of smooth intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In many concrete cases I find it quite hard to show the irreducibility of a given variety.

Can I proceed in the following way:

Situation: We look at the closed subscheme $$X = V(f_1, \dots, f_n) \subset \mathbb{P}^m_k.$$  for a algebraically closed field $k$. We can show that the Jacobian has everywhere full rank and hence $X$ is smooth of codimension $n$.

Argument: Any regular local ring is integral. Hence $X$ is reduced. So $X$ is a complete intersection (as schemes) and $f_1, \dots, f_n$ generate the homogeneous ideal of $X$ by Hartshorne, Exercise II, 8.4. By Hartshorne, Exercise III, 5.5 the variety $X$ is connected. However, any connected noetherian scheme with integral local rings is integral.

Is this argument even correct? Can the proof simplified?
What methods are there to show irreducibility in concrete situations?

Answer (score 1):

No: the transverse intersection of two conics in $\mathbb P^2_k$ is a complete intersection consisting of four smooth points but is certainly not irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for the simple example! Do you mean set / scheme /ideal theoretical complete intersection? I don't see, where exactly Hartshorne, Ex II, 8.4  goes wrong, which tells you, that complete intersections are connected.

Comment: @Casaubon: in the case Georges mentions, the complete intersection is not of dimension $\geq 1$, which seems necessary for Hartshorne Ex.II.8.4(c) to apply.

Comment: What I wrote is true in any sense I'm aware of. In the exercise Hartshorne assumes that the complete intersection is of dimension $\geq 1$, whereas in my example it has dimension $0$. [I see that Nils gave the same answer while I was composing mine]

Comment: Ok, then my argument should work, if we add, that $X$ has Dimension $\ge 1$?

Comment: @Casaubon: If by "full rank" you mean rank $n$, then yes, your argument is correct when $m-n>1$.